# Vuetify v-data-table wont show data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am a beginner in vue/javascript etc. Using vue cdn.

Have a flask api set up.

I cannot get a v-data-table to show any data at all! It will show headers and also update the number of lines in the pagination when I return data from the api.

Question 1:

I can't even get it to work with a static list in the javascript file. The table shows and the headers show but no data!!!:

script.js

```
const app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   vuetify: new Vuetify(),
   data: {
        headers: [{text:'cityname'},{text:'index'}],
        citylist: [{cityname:'London',index:21}]....................
```

index.html:

```
      <v-data-table
        :headers = "headers"
        :items="citylist"
        :items-per-page="10"
        caption = "City List"
        class="elevation-1"
        fixed
        style="max-height: 300px; overflow-y: auto"
      >
      </v-data-table>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you should split the 2nd question into a separate post

Comment: OK I did that. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for data it should be constructed like this.

```
data() {
    return {
      headers: [
        { text: "cityname",
          align: "left",
          sortable: false, 
          value: "cityname" 
        },
        { text: "index", value: "index" }
      ],
      citylist: [{cityname:'London',index:21}]
    }
}
```